# User task with both candidate group and candidate user

Tags: activiti

I have a scenario wherein a user task(A) is followed by another user task(B). And based on feedback of B, flow may go back to A.

Difference in two instantiations of A is that first time it is to be assigned based on a candidate group, while second time it is to be assigned to the exact user who actually worked on it first time(as feedback from A is for that specific user).

How can this be achieved?

I think I can have both activiti:candidateGroups and activiti:candidateUsers for A defined in process definition xml.

And then in java code I can query for all possible tasks for the user, and check accordingly.

Would it be a good approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, both *Candidate Groups* and *Candidate Users* are allowed on the same task. Activiti ignores (and apparently allows) null values in candidate assignment, so you can provide different variables both in *Candidate Groups* and *Candidate Users*, the one which is null will be ignored. you can nullify variable based on your logic of Task B.